# What is the best way to query this Department-Employee table to get the department which have the exact employees?

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, query-optimization

I am using MySQL 5.6. I have three tables

```
Employee(id, ..... PRIMARY KEY (id))
Department(id, ...., PRIMARY KEY (id))
Department_Employee(d_id, e_id,
 FOREIGN KEY(d_ID) REFERENCES Department(id),
 FOREIGN KEY(e_id) REFERENCES Employee(id)
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_D_E_Mapping PRIMARY KEY (e_id, d_id) )
```

Department and Employee have a many-many relationship.

Let's say  I'm given a list of Employee Ids(1, 2, 3) and I need to query the Department_employee table to get the Department_id which has only these 3 employees and no one else.

This is what I've managed to come up with so far.

```
SELECT id 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT d_id 
         from Department_employee 
        where e_id in (1, 2, 3)
     ) 
 GROUP 
    BY id HAVING COUNT = 3;
```

I feel like there is definitely a better way to do this.

How can this query be improved?

Comment: Well, you don't need a subquery - and there's no `id` here, so you're not quite telling us the truth

Comment: Note that it's always helpful to explicitly identify the PRIMARY KEY in each case, even when you think it's obvious.

Comment: Noted the PK point. thank you!. But, apart from the sub-query, how can i approach this?

Comment: Well, when you update your question, I might think about providing an answer ;-)

Comment: Updated with required info. :-)

Comment: You've missed out one of the tables !

Comment: i'm pretty sure this is good. :-)

Comment: Nope. You're still missing the PK. Either you have a surrogate id - in which case we would need to know whether a UNIQUE key existed on the remaining columns, or (better?) the PK is simply formed on (d_id,e_id) (Incidentally, I imagine it must be fantastically rare in the world for an employee to belong simultaneously to more than one department)

Comment: The department and Employee are just placeholders, xD. I don't think I am allowed to post Schemas directly from the company database. OOTH, i've updated the PK for DE table.. also, thanks for teaching proper standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by department id and use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT d_id 
FROM Department_employee
GROUP BY d_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(e_id ORDER BY e_id) = '1,2,3' -- the ids in ascending order
```

Or:

```
SELECT d_id 
FROM Department_employee
GROUP BY d_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 AND SUM(e_id NOT IN (1, 2, 3)) = 0
```

Comment: The second query was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!